# How to adjust a plot box from edges without using set_position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am making a plot for which I intend to make the plot have a certain amount of distance from the edges of the final saved file.

I have a figure in which I have two subplots which I want to have the distance from the edges. I am currently using NameOfSubplot.set_position in order to manually give distances from each edge but since I have to duplicate this for different plots and numbers, it takes a long time to find perfect numbers.

What can I use instead of set_position to give my subplots a specified edge boundary?
(Since I'm new to all this, I would appreciate it if you could type me the exact code for one subplot)

`python`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 7))

a = [1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010]
b = [2.5, 2.7, 2.8 , 3, 3.1]

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(121)
box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 +.05, box.width * 0.9, box.height * 0.9])   
l1 = ax1.plot(a, b, color='red')

ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(122)
box = ax1.get_position()
ax3.set_position([box.x0 +.4, box.y0 +.05, box.width*0.85, box.height*0.85])    
l2 = ax3.plot(a, b, color='cyan')
```

Comment: For example, if the figure is 16 inches wide and you want one inch padding on both sides, you would set `fig1.subplots_adjust(left=1/16, right=15/16)`

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by ImportanceOfBeingErnest*

> For example, if the figure is 16 inches wide and you want one inch padding on both sides, you would set:
>
> ```
> fig1.subplots_adjust(left=1/16, right=15/16)
> ```

Addition by user12321257:

> If we want spacing from top and bottom too, it will be something like this (assuming figure is 16 inches wide and 7 inches high):
>
> ```
> fig1.subplots_adjust(left= 1/16, right= 15/16, bottom = 1/7, top = 6/7)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. It's what I was looking for and it's easy to understand as well.
Just gonna add that if we want spacing from top and bottom too, it will be something like this (assuming figure is 16 inches wide and 7 inches high):
```python```
    fig1.subplots_adjust(left= 1/16, right= 15/16, bottom = 1/7, top = 6/7)

Comment: @user12321257, well, the thanks are for ImportanceOfBeingErnest :). It's a wiki post, feel free to edit it.